# 100% Ownership and 30% profit to sale director

Tags: limited-liability-company, sales-tax, start-up

I am seeking understanding. I 100% own a new service-based tech company. My business is registered as an LLC. I am about to launch and I seek to make sales, yet I don't have the resources to pay staff employees because I just spent between 30k - 60k for development of my tech services.

A friend is trying to handle sales of my services - Director of sales. 
While discussing these things were mentioned -
1. He will handle the training of sales team to work on commission. 
2. He promised to make 3 times my investment in the first year

Suggested terms - He will work with his resources but keep 30% profit after expenses cost. Basically he would be handling all things sales.

I am confused as to how this works because I still want to keep my 100% ownership. How is this deal written or is there a better way to document such terms?

Comment: Him getting a share of the profit does not give him any rights to make decisions, so you still own 100%. You could at any time cancel the agreement and let him go (which wouldn't be so fair if he does a good job); maybe you should agree to a time limit like two years and then renegotiate.

Comment: Thanks. But what happens in the event - the agreement was for 5 years and within that 5years period an offered was made to buyout. Would that buyout payment come in as revenue ? which profit would be shared?.

Comment: The buyer would be in the same situation you were in, unless your contract with the Director of Sales says that things change if ownership changes. So the buyer could retain him and then he would pay 30% to him. Or the buyer could terminate his arrangement with him as the terms in the contract with the Director of Sales specify.

Comment: You stated, "He promised to make 3 times my investment in the first year". You might want to ask yourself, "Or what?" Make sure to stipulate what happens if he doesn't meet that goal.

Comment: Thats right. Terms of not reaching that goal would be documented.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps an example will help make it more clear.

Any given year:  Revenue:  200K, profit 60K
You get 40K in profit, plus any salary, he gets 20K

Next year you attract the attention of a competitor and they offer and you accept to sell.  You would get 100% of the proceeds.

This is kind of a bad deal for him as you could easily play accounting tricks to diminish the company's profits and reduce his pay.  For the given example, you could pay yourself a 60K bonus and reduce the profit to zero and eliminate his compensation.  There should probably be a revenue metric included in his compensation.

**Edit:**
It is really nice to hear you have a desire to treat this person fairly.  Honesty in business is necessary for long term success.  I would simply make his salary dependent upon the revenue he generates.  For example, lets say you can make a widget for 4 and you expect to sell them for 10.  Your profit would be 6, and with the suggested split he would receive $2, you $4.

Instead I would have him receive like 15% of the revenue generated This allows for some discounts for bulk items and covers the cost of processing sales.  It also allows him to share revenue with his staff.

Alternatively you could also do a split.  Perhaps 7.5% of revenue and 10% of profit.

Comment: Thats right. can you suggest a revenue metric? My main focus is not to lose my friendship with him. So i want to be specific as possible in what i seek and how it could impact him in the event of a buyout.

Comment: Depending on your costs and price of the service, you might be able to word it as a percent of the sale. e.g. average sale is $10,000. The salesman gets $2000, the friend gets $1000. The numbers will be different. The point is to avoid the need to discuss your cost or profit with anyone. His numbers and salesman numbers go off of gross sales.